# Postgres permissions.yml for fileLoad(permissions.yml) CONFIG_ERROR

Tags: postgresql, configuration, loading, file-permissions, deepstream.io

I am following the https://deepstream.io/tutorials/plugins/database/postgres/
I have create a testDB with owner and permission to user james

In the conf/config.yml, I have the following configuration

```
 plugins:
  storage:
    name: postgres
    options:
      user: james
      database: testDB
      password: james
      host: localhost
      port: 5432 #postgres default post
      schema: ds #schema defaults to ds. Will be created if it doesn't exist
      max: 10 #concurrent connections
      idleTimeoutMillis: 30000 #timeout after which connection will be cut
      writeInterval: 200 #amout of milliseconds during which writes will be buffered
      notifications:
        CREATE_TABLE: true #Get notified when tables are created
        DESTROY_TABLE: true #Get notified when tables are dropped
        INSERT: true # Get notified when records are created
        UPDATE: false # Get notified when records are updated
```

However, when I run deepstream start, I got the following error

CONFIG_TRANSFORM | Loaded content from /Users/james/Workspace/deepstream.io/conf/permissions.yml for fileLoad(permissions.yml)
CONFIG_ERROR | Error loading module, exiting

Could someone please tell me what I have missed. Thank you for your help.

regards,

Johan

Answer (score 0):

finally, I solved the problem, the configuration is correct, just to make sure that the postgres database and the role is done properly. The role needs to have a password and also LOGIN. Also, I clone the codes from github, so I can see what the error is when npm start. This will shows you verbose error message. If no error shown, npm test, this will show you all the missing packages and try to npm install again